# Unity3D render GameObject as Wireframe

Tags: unity-game-engine, renderer, gameobject, wireframe

I am new to Unity3D and have a question about the rendering of gameobjects.
I needed the model from an .obj file so I just imported it and was able to place it as a prefab in the gameview. I also added a script for moving and turning this object.

What I wanted to do is to display the object as a wireframe so that a user recognizes the object structure but can see through it.
I found this example script to put on a camera

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Attach this script to a camera, this will make it render in wireframe
    void OnPreRender()
    {
        GL.wireframe = true;
    }

    void OnPostRender()
    {
        GL.wireframe = false;
    }
}
```

I got this example right from here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL-wireframe.html

My problem with this can be seen in the picture.
It somehow renders the objects two times. The wireframe one looks exactly like the one I wanted however the second one is strange and I don't know why it is there and how to get rid of this. The unwanted object also moves in parallel to the wireframe one if this helps to debug.
[image]

What is the best way to display the object as a wireframe?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have multiple cameras?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with [OnPostRender](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnPostRender.html) is not the way to go, as you change things after the camera already rendered them. If the object should always be shown as wireframe you should apply a wireframe shader to the objects [Material](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.html). AFAIK untiy does not have a build in wireframe shader, but there are multiple sites that have tutorials or [repos](https://github.com/Chaser324/unity-wireframe) that created a wireframe shader, you can find them easily if you google it.

Edit: here is an example from [Shaders Laboratory](http://www.shaderslab.com/demo-93---wireframe.html)

Edit 2: I presume you render the scene with two Camera's and the none wireframe object (which is the same object as the wireframe object) is the object that is rendered with the second camera that does not use the Wireframe. If you really want to use it this way, then you should add a [Layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) to the object and tell the other camera (under Culling Mask) not to render objects with this Layer.

Comment: As OP says it is the example from the [Unity API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL-wireframe.html) though ^^ And OP explicitly turns on the wireframe in `OnPreRender` so **before** stuff is rendered and turn it off in `OnPostRender` when it is no longer needed

Comment: while that is true, the "unwanted" object is the same object as the wireframed one and if OPs goal is to only show a wireframed object using OnPreRender and OnPostRender is not the way to go

Comment: To me it looks like there are multiple camera's .. otherwise there is no explanation why the object is rendered twice. And using a different shader ofcourse is a good hint in general, however it will not fully answer the question in that case because then it will just be rendered twice as wireframe ^^

Comment: @derHugo true, i added it to my answer as 2nd edit, this way it should work as desired with two cameras, but i would advise against using two cameras if it is not needed.

Comment: Thanks,  you both! I totally did not notice there already was another camera in the scene. What a beginner's mistake. I have not heard about shaders until now but I will definitely have a look, this sounds like a nice hint!